# Trust-Region Dogleg Method for Nonlinear Equations

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to write a trust-region algorithm using the dogleg method with python for a class I have. I have a Newton's Method algorithm and Broyden's Method algorthm that agree with each other but I can't seem to get this Dogleg method to work.

Here is the function I am trying to find the solution to:

```
def test_function(x):
    x1 = float(x[0])
    x2 = float(x[1])
    r = np.array([[x2**2 - 1],
                  [np.sin(x1) - x2]])
    return r
```

and here is the jacobian I wrote

```
def Test_Jacobian(x, size):
    e = create_ID_vec(size)
    #print(e[0])
    epsilon = 10e-8
    J = np.zeros([size,size])
    #print (J)
    for i in range(0, size):
        for j in range(0, size):
            J[i][j] = ((test_function(x[i]*e[j] + epsilon*e[j])[i] - test_function(x[i]*e[j])[i])/epsilon)
    return J
```

and here is my Trust-Region algorithm:

```
def Trust_Region(x):
    trust_radius = 1
    max_trust = 300
    eta = rand.uniform(0,.25)
    r = test_function(x) # change to correspond with the function you want
    J = Test_Jacobian(r, r.size) # change to correspond with function
    i = 0
    iteration_table = [i]
    function_table = [vector_norm(r, r.size)]
    while vector_norm(r, r.size) > 10e-10:
        print(x, 'at iteration', i, "norm of r is", vector_norm(r, r.size))
        p = dogleg(x, r, J, trust_radius)
        rho = ratio(x, J, p)
        
        if rho < 0.25:
            print('first')
            trust_radius = 0.25*vector_norm(p,p.size)
        elif rho > 0.75 and vector_norm(p,p.size) == trust_radius:
            print('second')
            trust_radius = min(2*trust_radius, max_trust)
        else:
            print('third')
            trust_radius = trust_radius
            
        if rho > eta:
            print('x changed')
            x = x + p
            #r = test_function(x)
            #J = Test_Jacobian(r, r.size)
        else:
            print('x did not change')
            x = x
            
        r = test_function(x) # change to correspond with the function you want
        J = Test_Jacobian(r, r.size) # change to correspond with function
        i = i + 1
        #print(r)
        #print(J)
        #print(vector_norm(p,p.size))
        print(rho)
        #print(trust_radius)
        iteration_table.append(i)
        function_table.append(vector_norm(r,r.size))
    print ('The solution to the non-linear equation is: ', x)
    print ('This solution was obtained in ', i, 'iteratations')
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.plot(iteration_table, np.log10(function_table))
    plt.xlabel('iteration number')
    plt.ylabel('function value')
    plt.title('Semi-Log Plot for Convergence')
    return x, iteration_table, function_table

def dogleg(x, r, J, trust_radius):
    tau_k = min(1, vector_norm(J.transpose().dot(r), r.size)**3/(trust_radius*r.transpose().dot(J).dot(J.transpose().dot(J)).dot(J.transpose()).dot(r)))
    p_c = -tau_k*(trust_radius/vector_norm(J.transpose().dot(r), r.size))*J.transpose().dot(r)
    
    if vector_norm(p_c, p_c.size) == trust_radius:
        print('using p_c')
        p_k = p_c
    else:
        p_j = -np.linalg.inv(J.transpose().dot(J)).dot(J.transpose().dot(r))
        print ('using p_j')
        tau = tau_finder(x, p_c, p_j, trust_radius, r.size)
        p_k = p_c + tau*(p_j-p_c)
    return p_k

def ratio(x, J, p):
    r = test_function(x)
    r_p = test_function(x + p)
    print (vector_norm(r, r.size)**2)
    print (vector_norm(r_p, r_p.size)**2)
    print (vector_norm(r + J.dot(p), r.size)**2)
    rho_k =(vector_norm(r, r.size)**2 - vector_norm(r_p, r_p.size)**2)/(vector_norm(r, r.size)**2 - vector_norm(r + J.dot(p), r.size)**2)
    return rho_k

def tau_finder(x, p_c, p_j, trust_radius, size):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, size):
        a = a + (p_j[i] - p_c[i])**2
        b = b + 2*(p_j[i] - p_c[i])*(p_c[i] - x[i])
        c = (p_c[i] - x[i])**2
    c = c - trust_radius**2
    tau_p = (-b + np.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
    tau_m = (-b - np.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
    #print(tau_p)
    #print(tau_m)
    if tau_p <= 1 and tau_p >=0:
        return tau_p
    elif tau_m <= 1 and tau_m >=0:
        return tau_m
    else:
        print('error')
        return 'error'

def model_function(p):
    r = test_function(x)
    J = Test_Jacobian(r, r.size)
    return 0.5*vector_norm(r + J.dot(p), r.size)**2
```

The answer should be about [[1.57076525], [1.        ]]
but here is the output after about 28-30 iterations:

```
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-359-a414711a1671> in <module>
      1 x = create_point(2,1)
----> 2 Trust_Region(x)

<ipython-input-358-7cb77bd44d7b> in Trust_Region(x)
     11         print(x, 'at iteration', i, "norm of r is", vector_norm(r, r.size))
     12         p = dogleg(x, r, J, trust_radius)
---> 13         rho = ratio(x, J, p)
     14 
     15         if rho < 0.25:

<ipython-input-358-7cb77bd44d7b> in ratio(x, J, p)
     71     print (vector_norm(r_p, r_p.size)**2)
     72     print (vector_norm(r + J.dot(p), r.size)**2)
---> 73     rho_k =(vector_norm(r, r.size)**2 - vector_norm(r_p, r_p.size)**2)/(vector_norm(r, r.size)**2 - vector_norm(r + J.dot(p), r.size)**2)
     74     return rho_k
     75 

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```